# Dicionary in javaScript print in the console

Tags: javascript, d3.js, console

I am going to search for a `csv` file for the data referring to suicides, given these`year` and `suicide_no`.
I want to make the sum of the number of suicides a year.
I have this code:

```
d3.csv("master.csv", function(error,data){
    if(error) console.log("Erro no ficheiro csv");

    var years = [];
    var suicides = [];

    var taxaAno = new Object();
    var taxaAno = {};

    data.forEach(function(d){
        years = +d.year;
        suicides = +d.suicides_no;


        if (taxaAno==null){
            taxaAno[years]= suicides;
        }
        else{
            taxaAno[years]+= suicides;
        }            


    });

    console.log(taxaAno);
});
```

I wanted the dictionary to come up in the end. But it looks like this:

```
 {1985: NaN, 1986: NaN, 1987: NaN, 1988: NaN, 1989: NaN, 1990: NaN, 1991: NaN, 1992: NaN, 1993: NaN, 1994: NaN, 1995: NaN, 1996: NaN, 1997: NaN, 1998: NaN, 1999: NaN, 2000: NaN, 2001: NaN, 2002: NaN, 2003: NaN, 2004: NaN, 2005: NaN, 2006: NaN, 2007: NaN, 2008: NaN, 2009: NaN, 2010: NaN, 2011: NaN, 2012: NaN, 2013: NaN, 2014: NaN, 2015: NaN, 2016: NaN}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if `taxaAno` is `null/undefined` instead of `taxaAno[years]`. Which means you always hit this line:

```
taxaAno[years]+= suicides;
```

So the first time, you're adding a number (`suicides`) to `undefined`. It should be:

```
   if (taxaAno[years] == null){
        taxaAno[years] = suicides;
   } else {
        taxaAno[years]+= suicides;
   }
```